# $\sigma$-additivity of integral in this setting

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

All definitions and conventions in this question follows RCA by Rudin.

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite positive measure. Let $1\le p <\infty$ and $f \in L^p(\mu)$.

Let $E$ be a measurable set. Then there is a countable partition $\{E_n\}$ of $E$ into measurable sets of finite measure. My question is that

$$ \int_E f \, d\mu \, = \, \sum_n \int_{E_n} f \, d\mu ? $$
If it is true, then do you have a nice proof?

Comment: This is certainly not true; in fact $\int_E f\,d\mu$ need not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p>1$, having $f\in L^p$ tells you nothing about the existence of $\int_Ef\,d\mu$. For the integral of $f$ to exist you need that at least one of $f^+$ and $f^-$ has finite integral. Thus it suffices to consider the case $f\geq0$. In such case,
\begin{align}
\int_Ef=\int_X1_E\,f=\int_X\sum_n1_{E_n}\,f=\sum_n\int_X1_{E_n}\,f=\sum_n\int_{E_n}\,f.
\end{align}
The exchange between the series and the integral is justified by Monotone Convergence.